# Why can't I call custom component's methods in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

so I developed and tested the whole project using Firefox and everything was just fine but when I tried to run it in Chrome, the browser kept saying that my custom components methods don't exist. Why is that? From what I know, Chrome supports Web Components.

[Link to the repository](https://github.com/xem0n/wordle)

Error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I've changed the class my components were deriving from (from HTMLDivElement to HTMLElement) and removed the `{ extends: 'div' }` option from their definition and everything started to work!